# ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing - Install pusher/pusher-http-laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5.4

I developing one Laravel Project with Realtime Notification's so i am using pusher/pusher-http-laravel Package.

When i install this packgae via composer it display following Errors.

```
Problem 1
    - pusher/pusher-php-server v3.0.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 3.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - pusher/pusher-http-laravel v4.0.0 requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[3.0.0, v3.0.1].
    - Installation request for pusher/pusher-http-laravel ^4.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-http-laravel[v4.0.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

In my System Environment i already enabled CURL Extension

[image]

How to solve this Error. My php version is 5.6

Comment: Your error clearly says you need php 7 for this package.

Comment: From the list of ini files that are parsed, it looks like you're running PHP 7 without Curl support. Are you sure you're running the versions you think you are? Bear in mind that the `phpinfo()` output in a browser doesn't necessarily reflect what's being used on the command-line.

Answer (score 3):

if you are updating the larval version, make sure to update the php version, and then you need to install/enable php curl.

on ubuntu you can run this cmd
`apt-get install php7.4-curl` . Make sure to replace with correct php version. (if you run `php -v` will give the php version)

then restart apache, this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade your PHP version from 5.6 to 7, then you need to downgrade your Laravel version to 5.1 in the composer.json file.

```
"require" : {
    "laravel/framework" : "5.1.*",
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue raise due to my Laravel Version and PHP Version. I fixed this Error install pusher/pusher-http-laravel Version 3.0.0.